# How to find missing triples after loading a graph to graphDB on Linux?

Tags: rdf, graphdb

I have uploaded an SWDF instance of about 200k triples to a graphDB installed in Linux VM. When I count the triples (using SPARQL count) I found that about 300 triples are missing. I want to find out the problem of the missing triples. 
Is there a way to get the entire triples in the graph back? or is there a log containing the triples that are not loaded?
The loading command looks like:

```
./graphdb/bin/loadrdf --force -c graphdb/config.ttl -m parallel myfile.nt
```

Comment: The docs provide a whole chapter for exporting data: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/exporting-data.html

Comment: but honestly, I'd check the log first - it's likely that the database would report triples that couldn't be loaded

Comment: To dump the entire repository use `curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/x-trig" "http://localhost:7200/repositories/<repositoryId>/statements?infer=false" > export.trig`